# In a Win32 app, how to retrieve app category information

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a Win32 app to monitor current process usage, and I hope my program is able to identify and categorise the app automatically. However, I cannot find any library to use in GitHub, and it seems like the Windows doesn't provide this kind of API. The only way I can think of is manually enter each app category into the database, but it seems overwhelming for users to manage all of his applications. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by app category?

Comment: Do you want to implement similar function like Task Manager that it groups processes into three categories: App, Background Process, and Windows Process?

Comment: I want to implement a function which can automatically categorise app into some categories like what App Store and Google Play did. For example, Facebook should be in the social category, steam should be game category. I am thinking whether it is possible to ask UWP store to provide such information given the app's name.

Comment: Such categories do not exist in the Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

This is overkill, but an answer I suppose. Make a text file, a local copy of which will be available and used by your app. The text file maps executable names to program categories.

Now, for auto-update of the mapping, put the shared master of this text file on "the cloud" - e.g. Google Docs. You could allow specific others to modify it, or just you. When the program starts, and then every hour or so, it opens that cloud text file for read only. Get the contents to see if the local copy needs to be superseded.

Comment: But the problem is how I can know which category the program belongs to. The best way I can think of is I define some built-in categories first, and allow users to change/add them. However, another problem is there are too many applications.